# BeanShell scripting as post processor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

How to capture response data into a list and to use those in next thread using BeanShell post processor?

Example: the response data was having:

> mobile number:1
>   mobile number:2
>   mobile number:3
>   mobile number:n

I want to capture all mobile numbers and want to use in next thread.

How to do that? Can any one tell?

Answer (score 0):

Using Beanshell for scripting is some form of a [performance anti-pattern](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) therefore I'll provide solution using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

1. Given you have response data like:

   ```
   mobilenumber:1 mobilenumber:2 mobilenumber:3
   ```
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above data and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   props.put('list',prev.getResponseDataAsString().split(" ").collect())
   ```

   The above code will split the response data by spaces and store the result into an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) structure
3. In the next Thread Group you will be able to access the values like:

   ```
   def list = props.get('list')
   ```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Store Variable as a list]

Comment: Thanks for this it is very useful .. but I want to store al the numbers into one list . my rrespone not only have mobilenumber it have lot of data from that data I want to caputure moile numbers into one list